# Firestore not loading or storing data to db swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I don't have any code for this, because the problem exist in all my calls to the database.

suddenly I can't load or store data to the database, but firestore still works in offline mode, so when I post a new message it shows up in the app but when I check my database in the firebase console the data is no where to be found.

I can still load pictures from storage so I know the app has connection.

Do anybody know what is causing this?

Swift 4
Firebase 4.9.0
Firestore 0.10.1

I have now created a testViewController with only a texField, Button and a activityIndicator, to see if I could write some data with a basic call.

This is my code and it only prints 1 and 4 and the activity indicator would keep animating.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    let database = Firestore.firestore()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func didTapStoreButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print(1)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        database.collection("test").document("testDocument").setData(["testString" : textField.text ?? ""]) { (error) in

            print(2)

            if error != nil {
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                print("Error adding document: \(error.debugDescription)")
            } else {
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                print("Document added")
            }

            print(3)
        }

        print(4)
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @AndréKool No errors. I have a uiactivityindicator that starts animating when the save button is tapped and stops animating when succeeded or failed, but it jus keeps animating.

Comment: Your calls to Firebase should, in general, all have error trapping so if a function fails, an error is logged to the console (for example). These errors are usually reported in the closures following the calls. This issue could be caused by a number of things so having more information is helpful in troubleshooting.

Comment: @Jay I do have error trapping, the problem is that it never fails or succeed, it just keeps running

Comment: Firebase is pretty good about capturing errors so this could be an edge case. However, some basic troublehshooting would help us to help you - add a breakpoint in your code and run the code (that works) to that breakpoint and then manually step through your code one line at a time until it *just keeps running*. That' segment of code should then be included in your question so we can have a chance of identifying the issue. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay So I tried to create a new view controller with within the same project to make a basic call, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!

So I have been struggling with this bug for hours and hours now and even deleted the app on my device and cleaned my xCode project and it still didn't fix it.

I decided to delete the app and clean the project once again, but before building the app on to my iOS device again I decided to restart my iOS device and that did it!

Comment: Okey this actually didn't work in the long way, the bug returned and I needed to delete the app again to fix it. Ended up rolling back to a older branch

Comment: I have the same problem in Android, so I tried to deleting a field with firebase console. The field was deleted but after refreshing the page the field appeared again!!! Maybe I have a bad config or some value is breaking firestore internals with no error report. I don't know, the error is intermitent.